# Getting list of contacts with Gnome-Shell JS interface

Tags: javascript, gobject, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

I've just started fiddling with writing gnome-shell extensions, and would like to know how to get a list of contacts a user has.

I've tracked down some likely files: `gnome-shell/js/ui/contactDisplay.js` and `gnome-shell/src/shell_contact_system.c`.

Now I notice in `shell_contact_system.c` the following function:

```
/**
 * shell_contact_system_get_all:
 * @self: A #ShellContactSystem
 *
 * Returns: (transfer none): All individuals
 */
GeeMap *
shell_contact_system_get_all (ShellContactSystem *self)
{
  GeeMap *individuals;

  g_return_val_if_fail (SHELL_IS_CONTACT_SYSTEM (self), NULL);

  individuals = folks_individual_aggregator_get_individuals (self->priv->aggregator);

  return individuals;
}
```

This suggests that inthe javascript interface I can use function `get_all` (my belief is reinforced by the fact that the `.c` file also has a `shell_contact_system_get_individual` and `contactDisplay.js` demonstrates the use of `Shell.ContactSystem.get_default().get_individual`), so I try:

```
contactSys = Shell.ContactSystem.get_default();
// get contacts
contacts = contactSys.get_all();
```

It works! (I'm trying it out in Gnome-shell's "looking glass" javascript interpreter).

It appears to be a 'Gobject' so I have no idea what to do with this object to get the names of my contacts out. I notice (from the C code) that this object is a `GeeMap *`, so looking at the [documentation for Gee.Map](http://people.gnome.org/~dvillevalois/libgee/doc/gee-1.0/Gee.Map.html), I see I can do the following:

```
contacts.size   // returns 31, which is the number of contacts I have !
contacts.values // is a Gee.Collection
contacts.keys   // is a Gee.Set
```

I then try to look at `contacts.values` and `contacts.key`, noting the `to_array()` method these have:

```
contacts.values.to_array()
contacts.keys.to_array()
```

However when I do this I get an **empty array** back out: `contacts.xxx.to_array().size` is 0, yet `contacts.size` is 31 ?? !!

The same occurs when I attempt to use a `contacts.map_iterator()` to iterate through the map; `it.get_value()` and `it.get_key()` appear to be null.

So, my question is: **How can I access the individual elements of `contacts`?**

I do note that the comment for `shell_contact_system_get_all` says `Returns: (transfer none): ...` whilst `shell_contact_system_get_individual` says `Returns: (transfer full): ...`, and the latter function works (provided I know the ID of the individual I want to look up, which is my problem), whereas the former doesn't. Could this be something to do with it?

Also, as a workaround, I can currently make use of the `contactSearchProvider` class to achieve this (used by the overview when you intall `gnome-contacts` where you can type the name of a contact and they'll appear in the overview). I basically search for `''` which should return me a list of every contact. It seems roundabout though - I feel I should just be able to use the `get_all()` method to get all the contacts without having to search on an empty string...

```
    const ContactDisplay = imports.ui.contactDisplay;
    cds = new ContactDisplay.contactSearchProvider;
    res = cds.getInitialResultSet(['']); 
    // woohoo! res.length is 31, and res[0], res[1], ... are all not null!
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated (by the way, is there any sort of documentation about for this? I feel extremely inadequate when I stare at the source and try to deduce all the documentation from it!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a bug and that you already found where it is: the annotation on the C method should say `Returns: (transfer full):` in order to give back results to the bindings.

The next logical step would be to report the bug and the patch to their bugzilla, but I need to note that code was removed in gnome 3.6 so I'm skeptical it will be ever fixed.

The contact search code now lives in the gnome-contact app at:

http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-contacts

Comment: Yeah, figured as much (I asked around the #gnome-shell IRC once and basically the gobject support for Folks/Gee was not very complete - doesn't surprise me that they dropped it)